# In oracle How to subtract previous value in a column with calculation of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a requirement for a table as shown below. As you can see `mgt_year`,`tot_dflt_mgt` and `to_accum_mgt` columns. In year column where its **2016** the value is **39.772773** and accum value is **1380.055**.What I want is that when I do `(to_accum_mgt - tot_dflt_mgt)` I want this calculated result in previous row as shown in the image. Then this calculated result i.e. **1340.282227** is used for subtracting **65.7915** like **(1340.282227 - 65.7915)** for year **2015** and so on for all trailing years.
I have done this in excel, but the how to achieve this result in Oracle and in SQL server .
Please forgive My bad English and noob formatting.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You need to explain very clearly what are the INPUTS and what is the desired OUTPUT. If I understand correctly, you are given several rows by three columns. What is given is the year in every row, the `tot_dflt_mgt` value for every row, and `tot_accum_mgt` for the last row, and from these inputs you must calculate `tot_accum_mgt` for every row. Is that correct? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes the 3rd column will have calculated values. In 3rd column `tot_accum_mgt` only value is given for year **2016** all the values above are calculated.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help. Can you please suggest solution for this problem using SQL server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small table similar to yours for testing purposes. Then the query at the bottom shows how to solve this kind of problem, using analytic functions. There is no row-by-row processing needed.

```
create table t ( mgt_year, tot_dflt_mgt, tot_accum_mgt ) as (
       select 2013, 10, null from dual union all
       select 2014, 15, null from dual union all
       select 2015,  9, null from dual union all
       select 2016, 20, 600  from dual
);

select * from t;

MGT_YEAR TOT_DFLT_MGT TOT_ACCUM_MGT
-------- ------------ ------------
    2013           10   
    2014           15   
    2015            9   
    2016           20          600


select mgt_year, tot_dflt_mgt,
       max(tot_accum_mgt) over () - 
         nvl( sum(tot_dflt_mgt) over 
                   (order by mgt_year 
                          rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
            , 0 ) as tot_accum_mgt
from   t;

MGT_YEAR TOT_DFLT_MGT TOT_ACCUM_MGT
-------- ------------ -------------
    2016           10           556
    2014           15           571
    2015            9           580
    2016           20           600
```

Comment: Thank you Very much. this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help.  Can you please suggest solution for this problem using  SQL server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps join each row to its previous year?

`Select
      y1.mgt_year
     ,y2.mgt_year
     ,(y1.to_accum_mgt - y2.tot_accum_mgt) as myresult
from mytable y1
inner join mytable y2
on y1.mgt_year = (y2.mgt_year -1)`

Comment: This won't work, since most values `y1.to_accum_mgt` will be `null` when you start, so the result of the subtraction will also be `null`. You are probably thinking of computing the answers in succession, but that's not how SQL works.

Comment: @mathguy, no I understood the OP to mean that the image was the input table, perhaps I misunderstand.  The table that you created has NULLs in the third column, his does not. But perhaps the OP means that is the output he is looking for.

Comment: You do misunderstand. See the exchange below the original post, where I asked the OP and he confirmed. I find that it is always best to go through that process before attempting to solve a problem. I did the same in this case.